# ruby on rails make table changes adding rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Very new to ruby on rails. I created a scaffold called page which gave me some pre-defined pages to go along with it. I also made an index, that lets me view what all has been created on my page..my question is how I can alter the table...

```
<h1>Listing recipes</h1>

<tbody>
<% @recipes.each do |recipe| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= recipe.username %></td>
    <td><b><%= recipe.title %></b></td>
    <td><%= recipe.recipe %></td>, 
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', recipe %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_recipe_path(recipe) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', recipe, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'Add New Recipe', new_recipe_path %>
```

all of the above was pretty much done for me...I am trying to break up the table so that recipe.recipe shows on a new line I have tried  with no success! I just get the same result as before...

example:

```
<tbody>
<% @recipes.each do |recipe| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= recipe.username %></td>
    <td><b><%= recipe.title %></b></td>
   </tr> 
   <tr>
   <td><%= recipe.recipe %></td>, 
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', recipe %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_recipe_path(recipe) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', recipe, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>

<br>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean *the same result as before*; do you mean literally, the dom structure is not changed, or are you able to verify that you do in fact have two `<tr>` rows for each recipe?

Comment: by same result as before I mean the table structure has not changed. It looks the same as it did without the additional <tr> tag

Comment: Ok. Lets eliminate the obvious first (not meant to be patronising, just due diligence): Are you sure you're editing the correct file (should be the file at the path `views/recipes/index.html.erb`? Additionally, check your `config/development.rb` and ensure that `config.cache_classes = false`. If it is true, that could be the problem.

Comment: it is the correct file app/views/recipes/index.html.erb however i can't locate config/development.rb.. I have within the config file: application.rb, boot.rb, database.yml, environment.rb,  & routes.rb

Comment: sorry I meant `config/environments/development.rb`

Comment: Not sure if this has anything to do with your issue, but you have a comma after one of your closing </td> tags that shouldn't be there.  You also have a closing </table> tag but no opening <table> tag.

Comment: OK, thanks I added the opening <table> and it worked! thanks